# responsive html5 template with responsive Slider/Gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, gallery

I've got a problem with a new created page:

I used the arcana template by html5up (http://html5up.net/arcana/) and created my site. Additonally I added a flexslider Gallery (http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) for pictures.

Everything works fine except the mobile-Version of the gallery-page. On this page I don't have the page-header and the side-menu:

normal page:
http://www.dr-schrutz.at/index.html

Gallery page:
http://www.dr-schrutz.at/ordination.html

I already tried other sliders as well. Same problem everywhere.

Everything is fine on the normal Page. I think there is an issue with jquery but I have no idea where to look at.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kelzama

Comment: Somehow your ```<div id="skel-panels-fixedWrapper">``` is getting removed on the gallery page. It's in the HTML file, right?

Comment: I did not found it. I found it in skel-panel.min.js:
`b.cache.fixedWrapper=jQuery('<div id="skel-panels-fixedWrapper" />').appendTo(b.cache.body);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered elsewhere, you're loading jQuery twice on the Gallery page (once in the header and once before the body closes) which is probably the cause.